# Subclass constructor refuses to accept any name-value arguments

Tags: matlab, validation, oop, arguments, instantiation

#### TL;DR

I am having an issue with the `arguments` functionality, wherein a subclass fails to instantiate if *any* name-value argument pairs are passed to it.

(Class definitions are given at the end.)

---

The [`arguments`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arguments.html) functionality, introduced in R2019b, brings great promise in terms of simplifying argument validation and removing boilerplate code from functions <sup>[[1]](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2019/11/07/time-for-an-argument/)</sup>. However, upon trying to implement *name-value* (NV) arguments taken from [`public` class properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-argument-validation-1.html#mw_de9b2056-9dc2-421c-9c7e-d2c4400a95be), I got the following error:

```
Invalid argument list. Check for wrong number of positional arguments or placement of positional arguments after 
name-value pairs. Also, check for name-value pairs with invalid names or not specified in pairs.
```

before any subclass code is even executed. This message is confusing, because tab-completion appears to work as expected for NV pairs:

[image]

Moreover, if no arguments are passed at all, everything works fine:

```
>> FluidLayer()
ans = 
  FluidLayer with properties:

    prop1: NaN
    prop2: NaN
```

vs.

```
>> FluidLayer('prop1',1)
Error using FluidLayer
Invalid argument list. ...
```

**Questions:**

1. Why am I getting an error? I don't think I'm using the `arguments` mechanism in some unintended or undocumented way, so I'm doubly puzzled about what I might be doing wrong (assuming this is not a bug).
2. What can be done to resolve this, other than abandoning the whole `arguments` approach (I would like to keep argument name suggestions)? I have considered transitioning to `varargin` and/or using the [`functionSignatures.json` approach](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/customize-code-suggestions-and-completions.html) - but these require significantly more work.

---

```matlab
classdef Layer < handle & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous

  properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = protected)
    prop1(1,1) double {mustBeNonempty} = NaN
    prop2(1,1) double {mustBeNonempty} = NaN
  end % properties

  methods (Access = protected)

    function layerObj = Layer(props)
      % A protected/private constructor means this class cannot be instantiated
      % externally, but only through a subclass.
      arguments
        props.?Layer
      end

      % Copy field contents into object properties
      fn = fieldnames(props);
      for idxF = 1:numel(fn)
        layerObj.(fn{idxF}) = props.(fn{idxF});
      end
    end % constructor
  end % methods

end
```

```matlab
classdef FluidLayer < Layer

  properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = protected)
    % Subclass-specific properties

  end % properties

  methods 
    function layerObj = FluidLayer(props)
      arguments
        props.?FluidLayer
      end

      % Create superclass:
      propsKV = namedargs2cell(props);
      layerObj = layerObj@Layer(propsKV{:});

      % Custom modifications:

    end % constructor
  end % methods

end
```

Comment: Does it work for `Layer`? I think MATLAB does funny things with properties of superclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been able to simplify your example to this:

```matlab
classdef Layer

    properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = protected)
        prop1
        prop2
    end % properties

    methods

        function layerObj = Layer(props)
            arguments
                props.?Layer
            end
            disp(props)
        end % constructor

    end % methods

end
```

Now `Layer('prop1',1)` throws an error as you describe.

Thus, it has nothing to do with subclassing or inheritance.

However, if we remove the `SetAccess = protected` restriction (leaving the properties with public get and set access), then it all works as you expected.

I don't know why restricting set access would limit this use case, as it has nothing to do with writing those properties, and a class method should have set access anyway. My guess is that this is a bug.

Comment: Well, after reading the documentation of this functionality more thoroughly, I noticed it was specifically stated that the `.?classname` trick only works on properties with **`public` `SetAccess`**. I am accepting this answer because it mentions the documented course of action as of R2020a.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of R2020a states that the `structName.?ClassName` syntax can only be used with "*settable properties defined by a class (that is, all properties with `public` `SetAccess`)*". Thus, using it with `protected` properties is explicitly unsupported.

As such, if we want to use the "automatic" `arguments` validation mechanism, we have no choice but to set the `SetAccess` to `public`. However, this solution exposes the object properties to unwanted external changes, and so a workaround is suggested based on several principles:

1. `properties` now have `public` `SetAccess`, as required by the documentation.
2. Custom setters are added that perform access validation based on `dbstack` and `meta.class` comparison.

New `Layer.m` (notice the 2 new `methods` blocks):

```matlab
classdef Layer < handle & matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous

  properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = public)
    prop1(1,1) double {mustBeNonempty} = NaN
    prop2(1,1) double {mustBeNonempty} = NaN
  end % properties

  %% Constructor
  methods (Access = protected)

    function layerObj = Layer(props)
      % A protected/private constructor means this class cannot be instantiated
      % externally, but only through a subclass.
      arguments
        props.?Layer
      end

      % Copy field contents into object properties
      fn = fieldnames(props);
      for idxF = 1:numel(fn)
        layerObj.(fn{idxF}) = props.(fn{idxF});
      end
    end % constructor

  end % protected methods  

  %% Setters & Getters  
  methods

    function set.prop1(obj, val)
      if Layer.getCallerMetaclass() <= ?Layer
        obj.prop1 = val;
      else
        Layer.throwUnprotectedAccess();
      end
    end

    function set.prop2(obj, val)
      if Layer.getCallerMetaclass() <= ?Layer
        obj.prop2 = val;
      else
        Layer.throwUnprotectedAccess();
      end
    end

  end % no-attribute methods

  %% Pseudo-protected implementation  
  methods (Access = protected, Static = true)

    function throwUnprotectedAccess()
      stack = dbstack(1);
      [~,setterName,~] = fileparts(stack(1).name);      
      throw(MException('Layer:unprotectedPropertyAccess',...
        ['Unable to set "', stack(1).name(numel(setterName)+2:end),...
        '", as it is a protected property!']));
    end    

    function mc = getCallerMetaclass()
      stack = dbstack(2, '-completenames');
      if isempty(stack)
        mc = ?meta.class;
      else
        [~,className,~] = fileparts(stack(1).file);
        mc = meta.class.fromName(className);
      end
    end

  end % protected static methods
end % classdef
```

New `FluidLayer.m` (the `foo` method was added):

```matlab
classdef FluidLayer < Layer

  properties (GetAccess = public, SetAccess = protected)
    % Subclass-specific properties

  end % properties

  methods
    %% Constructor
    function layerObj = FluidLayer(props)
      arguments
        props.?Layer
      end

      % Create superclass:
      propsKV = namedargs2cell(props);      
      layerObj = layerObj@Layer(propsKV{:});
    end % constructor

    function obj = foo(obj)
      obj.prop1 = obj.prop1 + 1;
    end

  end % methods
end % classdef
```

Here's a demonstration of how it works:

```matlab
>> fl = FluidLayer('prop1', 2, 'prop2', 1)
fl = 
  FluidLayer with properties:

    prop1: 2
    prop2: 1

>> fl.prop1 = 5;  % attempting to set property directly (unintended)
Error using Layer/throwUnprotectedAccess (line 51)
Unable to set "prop1", as it is a protected property!
Error in Layer/set.prop1 (line 32)
        Layer.throwUnprotectedAccess(); 

>> fl.foo()       % attempting to set property through method (intended)
ans = 
  FluidLayer with properties:

    prop1: 3
    prop2: 1
>>
```

In conclusion: it is possible to overcome the `SetAccess = public` limitation using setter methods, but convoluted modifications to class code are required.

Practical Notes:

1. The `getCallerMetaclass` is limited in that it doesn't correctly identify packages - resulting in potentially empty metaclass objects. So keep in mind that this function should be modified if that is the case.
2. `dbstack` is called multiple times, although it is not necessary (it can be called once in the setter and the result can then be passed around).
3. The setter code for different properties is 5-lines long and mostly replicated (with the exception of the property name) - this can be improved by grabbing the property name through `dbstack`.